# How to route from page to another page using props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a home page with list of some addresses which are rendered in table for react js. Now I need to add functionality where if I click on any address it leads to new page with its details.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to narrow a bit your question, but an example can be:

1.- Set the route, in the components where your routes are set, for this example the route `/project/:id`:

```
<Route
    path='/project/:id'
    render={(props) => (
        <ProjectDetails {...props}/> //I WANT TO GET THE PASSED PROP IN THE LINK HERE
    )}
/>
```

2.- From the component where you define the link, pass the props in the `state` like this example, where an object with the `fromNotifications` property is passed:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/tylermcginnis',
  state: {
    fromNotifications: true
  }
}}>Tyler McGinnis</Link>
```